# best figure format in terms of resolution?

Tags: floats, charts

I am learning latex recently and I want to add figures, charts, maps to my paper. What is the best figure formats in terms of resolution? I have some charts and it has many numbers on them. The numbers are pretty small and I want them to be easily readable. Also, can anyone explain the code. 
Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: What code is it that you want explained?

Comment: Use vector graphics, convert it to `tikz` using inkscape, and include the file to your latex file.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the possibility to obtain a vector graphics, it is the best solution, because it is scalable. An exemplary format is PostScript (*.ps and *.eps iles), but all depends on tools that you are using and a version of TeX (tex/pdftex engine) you want to use.

Comment: also pdf and svg

Comment: @Mark PDF is a lot easier to use with TeX than SVG... @ Kola B. If using pdfTeX, EPS will get converted to PDF anyway, so PDF is at least as good, if not better, in that case. But for TeX, of course, EPS is essential.